# How to see the console of a django server running with nohup command?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-logging

I am coming from java background so please bear with my question, for normally applications running on tomcat there is a file named `catalina.out` which contains all the information written to Tomcats System.in and System.out. There is a django project running on a production server and I need to see logs, so far no logger has been configured so I have no idea where to look for server console.
Can some one help me with this?

Comment: in the place from where you have ran `nohup python manage.py runserver &` will have a file called `nohup.out` i.e you are looking for. but for production you need to use different approach

Comment: What approach should I follow? I am fairly new to this and the application was already developed by someone, so what do you suggest any resource?

Comment: see how to deploy django application with nginx gunicorn and supervisor